# Grouping data by range to make a histogram

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a life time value histogram chart in C#.

I'd like to group the data into $10 buckets.  I'm trying to find a way where I don't have to explicitly define each bucket.

The output would be something like this:

```
Range : Count  
0-10 : 23  
10-20 : 40  
20-30 : 43
```

ect...

I also have a Member table; lets say he has two fields.

```
int Id
Decimal LifeTimeValue
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ that doesn't require me to explicitly define each bucket?

Here's what I've done so far in SQL. I can easily port this into LINQ, but this is a bad approach as I'll have to duplicate a when clause for each bucket.

```
select
case when LifeTimeValue >= 0 and LifeTimeValue < 10    then '  0 - 10'
           when LifeTimeValue > 10 and LifeTimeValue <= 20   then ' 10+ - 20'
           when LifeTimeValue > 20 and LifeTimeValue <= 30  then ' 20+ - 30'
           else 'over 30'
end As PriceRange,
count(LifeTimeValue) as ItemTotal
from tblMember
group by 
case when LifeTimeValue >= 0 and LifeTimeValue < 10    then '  0 - 10'
           when LifeTimeValue > 10 and LifeTimeValue <= 20   then ' 10+ - 20'
           when LifeTimeValue > 20 and LifeTimeValue <= 30  then ' 20+ - 30'
           else 'over 30'
end;
```

Comment: http://sscce.org/. `I'm looking for the linq query that would create this for me.` is not a question.

Comment: Where is your unsuccessful attempt?

Comment: This is a very lazy attempt at a question. Where is your attempt to solve this? There is not even a question mark anywhere to be seen either.

Comment: I didn't think putting in an unsuccessful attempt would clarify the question or add any value.  I've added one now to make you guys happy.

Comment: @sscce.org Correct. I can see how it could be hard to figure out what I'm asking for since there is no question mark.

Comment: Tough crowd....I thought this was a good question

Comment: @Aducci Thanks for responding and helping me :).

Comment: @Aducci - Perhaps vote on reopening. I have. I think this question was fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key part is:  `x.LifeTimeValue - (x.LifeTimeValue % 10)`

```
var query = from x in context.Member
            group x by x.LifeTimeValue - (x.LifeTimeValue % 10) into x
            select new
            {
              Range = x.Key,
              Count = x.Count()
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

It is important when creating a histogram that you cover the case where a bucket may have no data. A result of `0` for a bucket is important.

It's also probably wise to provide the data in bucket order.

First make a lookup:

```
var lookup = context.Member.ToLookup(x => (int)x.LifeTimeValue / 10);
```

Changing to `int` allows integer division to make the buckets.

Now we need to find the extent of the data:

```
var smallest = lookup.Min(x => x.Key);
var largest = lookup.Max(x => x.Key);
```

Now the query is easy:

```
var query =
    from x in Enumerable
        .Range(smallest, largest - smallest + 1)
    select new
    {
        Range = String.Format("{0}-{1}", x * 10, (x + 1) * 10),
        Count = lookup[x].Count(),
    };
```

Here's my result from some sample data I created:

[image: histogram data]

Note that the range `10-20` has `0` for the count.